# Stop a scheduling job from rest endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, job-scheduling, spring-scheduled

I am doing a Spring Boot Project

This is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages="blabla.quartz")
@EnableScheduling
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context =SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);     
    }

}
```

This is the controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private SampleTask m_sampletask;

    @Autowired TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture;
    int jobid=0;

    @RequestMapping(value = "start/{job}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void start(@PathVariable String job) throws Exception {
        m_sampletask.addJob(job);

        Trigger trigger = new Trigger(){

            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                org.quartz.CronExpression cronExp=null;
                CronSequenceGenerator generator = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 * * ? * *");
                Date nextExecutionDate = generator.next(new Date());
                System.out.println(nextExecutionDate);              
                return nextExecutionDate;

            }

        };                          
        scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.schedule(m_sampletask, trigger);

    }

}
```

This is the ScheduleConfigurer implementation

```
@Service
public class MyTask implements SchedulingConfigurer{    

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        scheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("somegroup-");
        scheduler.setPoolSize(10);      
        scheduler.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        scheduler.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(20);
        return scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    }   

}
```

This is the class which I am calling from controller as scheduled job

```
@Component
public class SampleTask implements Runnable{

    private List<String> jobs=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String jobName;

    public void addJob(String job){
        jobName=job;
    } 

    @Override
    public void run() {     
        System.out.println("Currently running "+jobName);       
    }
}
```

How to stop the schedule job by a rest endpoint(Suppose "/stop/{jobname}").. When I have started the job using the "/start/{jobname}" rest endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use the quartz scheduler (if not already), and add a service with the required methods, then inject that service into your controller.

There's a decent example here: https://github.com/javabypatel/spring-boot-quartz-demo

If you want an in-memory job store (that isn't a database), checkout the RAMJobStore: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigRAMJobStore.html

#### Stop Example

This is an excerpt from the demo project. Credit goes to Jayesh Patel: https://github.com/javabypatel

```
/**
 * Stop a job
 */
@Override
public boolean stopJob(String jobName) {
    System.out.println("JobServiceImpl.stopJob()");
    try{    
        String jobKey = jobName;
        String groupKey = "SampleGroup";

        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
        JobKey jkey = new JobKey(jobKey, groupKey);

        return scheduler.interrupt(jkey);

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        System.out.println("SchedulerException while stopping job. error message :"+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey Pytry . Thanks for your answer.. but I can't have a database in my application which is must for quartz.

Comment: Quartz does not require that you have a persisted database for your JobStore. You could use an in-memory embedded database like H2, or you could also use the RAMJobStore (see updated answer).